# How to distinguish nested cell arrays

Tags: matlab

I need to parse a function parameter `gVars` with the following structure:

```
{ {'var1', 1}, { {'var2', 2}, {'var3', 3} } }
```

Basically it always have two elements. Each element can be a cell array like `{'var', value}` or an array containing nested cell arrays, like `{{-} [, {-}]+}` in the example above. I do not want to force the user to enclose the first type of values (`{'var', val}`) in double parenthesis like this `{{'var', val}}` (if there is only one variable, then the user is free to use a 1-level cell array).

I implemented this code:

```
for ii=1:length(gVars)
    disp 'Current group'
    curGroup = gVars{1, ii}
    for jj=1:length(curGroup)
        disp 'Current group content'
        content = curGroup{1, jj}
        allColumns = {allColumns{:}, content{1}};
    end
end
```

The error is:

```
Current group
curGroup = 
    'var'    []

Current group content
content =
var

Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
```

Basically I am not able to distinguish between these two types of cell array with length 2:

```
{'v1', val1}
{ {'v2', val1}, {'v3', val3} }
```

which are both cell array with length 2. With `{'v1', val1}`, it fails when I try and access the variable name with `content{1}` because it has already selected the string `'v1'`. The code obviously works with the second parameter and it would be ok if I forced the first type of values to be `{{'v1', val1}}`.

So basically, the question is: how can I distinguish between the two cell arrays above? Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Maybe some check with [`iscell`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html)?

Comment: More importantly, why use nested cell arrays at all and just regular parameter/value pairs?

Comment: Flexibility for future functionalities (individual options for name-value pairs).

Comment: The [`addParameter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.addparameter.html) method of MATLAB's [`inputParser`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html) class may be helpful rather than creating your own input parser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iscell` on the 1st item

```
home
val1 = 1; val2 = 2; val3 = 3;
test{1} = {'v1', val1};
test{2} = { {'v2', val1}, {'v3', val3} };

for ii=1:length(test)
  if iscell ( test{ii}{1} )
    fprintf ( 'do this for %s\n', test{ii}{1}{1} )
  else
    fprintf ( 'do this for %s\n', test{ii}{1} )
  end
end
```